# android getSkuDetails returning error

Tags: android, in-app-billing

In-app billing call to getSkuDetails is returning a response of
BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR
which is described as:
    Invalid arguments provided to the API. This error can also indicate that the application was not correctly signed or properly set up for In-app Billing in Google Play, or does not have the necessary permissions in its manifest

This is from the Production APK with my developer id. I am 100% sure that this worked a couple of months ago. I would get an error message when I actually tried to purchase an item (developer can't purchase their own items) -- but I used to be able to make this call successfully.

This is important to me because this is how I validate that new items that I list are actually available and priced correctly.

So what I need to know is: did something change in the API so that getSkuDetails is now invalid from the developer account? Or have I somehow corrupted some code that used to work?

Answer (score 0):

Found my bug.  It was due to some code that I reorganized a couple of versions ago.
In my case the BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR  was due to having duplicates SKUs in my query list. 
Removing the duplicates solved the problem.